# How to change that column in react / tsx / styled-component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, tsx

I'm working on a youtube clone project for school. I need to make 4 videos be shown in the container when my menu is open (boolean / true) and 5 when it is closed (false). I tried to do this using the following code, but to no avail (the amount doesn't change in the project no matter what the boolean value

```js
import { ChannelImage, Container, ImagemBanner, TextCard, TextContainer, Title, TitleContainer } from "./styles";

function VideoComponent({ openMenu }: { openMenu: boolean }) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <ImagemBanner src="https://pm1.narvii.com/5929/71e33a3add7f81140ea6fa81a564b98ec377fbb6_hq.jpg"></ImagemBanner>
      <TitleContainer>
        <ChannelImage>
          AZ
        </ChannelImage>
        <TextContainer>
          <Title>Teste</Title>
          <TextCard>Arthur</TextCard>
          <TextCard> 68 mi visualizações - há 1 ano</TextCard>
        </TextContainer>
      </TitleContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default VideoComponent;
```

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
`;

export const ImagemBanner = styled.img`
    width: 100%;
    height: 210px;
    border-radius: 12px;
`;

export const TitleContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
`;

export const ChannelImage = styled.div`
    background-color: beige;
    width: 40px;
    heigth: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
`;

export const TextContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`;

export const Title = styled.span`
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #0f0f0f;
`;

export const TextCard = styled.span`
    color: 8c8c8c;
    font-size: 14px;
`;
```

```js
import VideoComponent from "../../components/videoComponent";
import { Container } from "./styles";

interface IProps {
  openMenu: boolean;
}


function Home({ openMenu }: IProps) {
  return (
    <Container openMenu={openMenu}>
      <VideoComponent openMenu={openMenu}/>
      <VideoComponent openMenu={openMenu}/>
      <VideoComponent openMenu={openMenu}/>
      <VideoComponent openMenu={openMenu}/>
      <VideoComponent openMenu={openMenu}/>
      <VideoComponent openMenu={openMenu}/>
      <VideoComponent openMenu={openMenu}/>
      <VideoComponent openMenu={openMenu}/>
      <VideoComponent openMenu={openMenu}/>
      <VideoComponent openMenu={openMenu}/>
      
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

```js
import { styled } from "styled-components";

export const Container = styled.div<{ openMenu: boolean }>`
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: ${({ openMenu }) => openMenu? 'repeat(4, 1fr)' : 'repeat(5, 1fr)'};
    column-gap: 20px;
    row-gap: 50px;

`;
```

I need to make the column change according to the boolean, however the main objective, leaving the boolean completely aside, is to change the number of columns with my side menu open and closed